# Angular2 get google Analytics Id from service and add it to index.html

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I have added the following code in my index.html

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');

</script>
```

I would like to get the UA number from a service and not hardcode it here, since it changes based on the environment we are on. I would like to know how to make the service call and inject this value.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it, not sure if its the best way.

```js
<script>
  var id ='';
  var propertiesUrl = '../someurl';
  function httpGet()
  {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", propertiesUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
    id = jsonResponse.analyticsId;


    if (xmlHttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
      (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
          }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
          m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
      })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
      ga('create', id, 'auto');
    }


  }
  httpGet();


</script>
```